# Javascript to get the ID of tr on checkbox checked and enable/disable button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsom, jquery-ui

I have a table which creates dynamically with each row a check box. The Format is Like below(screenshot).
[image]
Now when the user selects the first row check box we need to get the Id of that "tr" and make the input type Button Enabled.

of that particular row .Once the checkbox is unchecked it should disable the edit button only for that particualr row.

Can any one help me on the below scenario. I have put the dom tree in scree shot above

Comment: You put eventlistners on the checkbox with code that walks up the DOM to the TR, then use TRelement.querySelector to target the edit button inside the TR. BUT What does this have to do with SharePoint?

Comment: Actually i am fetching the  sharepoint list data in html table and adding each row a check box .Now when the check box is checked i want to enable edit button and on click of the edit button i want to pass the ID and redirect to editform.aspcof the SPListItem.Now i got the id $(document).on('change','.chcktbl',function(){var listid= $(':checkbox:checked').closest('tr').attr('id');alert(listid);}}); but can't able to achieve the scenario

Comment: are you unable to get listid or checkbox change event is not firing?

Comment: I am able to ge the table row id on check box selected.but this event fires for other check boxes as well.also when it is unchecked the id is undefined

Comment: sorry I don't do jQuery anymore, forgot all about its syntax, native JS is way faster

Answer (score 0):

I would really recommend using one of the modern frameworks. It makes it some much easier to deal with these nasty event subscriptions, hiding, enabling, disabling, etc.

For example, this is how it could look like in AngularJs:

```
 <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
      <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
      <td>{{item.Title}}</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked"></td>
      <td><input type="text" ng-disabled="!item.checked"></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

Here is a simple example: https://plnkr.co/edit/MtsN2C?p=preview

If you are using SharePoint 2013+ then you can take advantage of the REST API:

```
var url = "/sites/demo/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('News')/items?$select=Title,Name&$top=10";
$http({
   url: url,
   method: "GET",
   headers: [Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose"]
})
.then(function (results) {
    vm.items = results.data.value;
});
```